# Change $HOME before it gets accessed

Tags: vimrc, microsoft-windows

I'm using vim 8.1 on windows.
The IT department has set $HOME to a slow network drive.
Every time a file gets written to $HOME vim slows down.

I have $VIM/vimrc with the following content.

```
let $HOME = $USERPROFILE
```

This used to work, but now netrw still creates files on the network drive.

How do I change $HOME so that no slowdown occurs?

Comment: Does `:echo $HOME` and `:echo expand("$HOME")` print what you expect? (Just to make sure it is not reset afterwards.)

Comment: Yes, it does print what I expect

Answer (score 8):

After you answered the question yourself, the focus shifted. It seems the Question is now "How can I prevent Vim from checking for `$HOME/_vimrc`?".

Try the following:

- Create the file `$USERPROFILE/vimrc` with all your configuration.
- Create the environment variable `VIMINIT` with the value `source $USERPROFILE/vimrc`.

On startup the variable `VIMINIT` is checked first. If it is set, the value of `$VIMINIT` is used as an Ex command line.

---

Update (I know that the questioner is not interested anymore):

You should also check your `runtimepath`. Most likely it still points to `$HOME/vimfiles` (on Windows). So you should create the directory `$USERPROFILE/vimfiles` to store extended configuration and plugins etc.

At the beginning of `$USERPROFILE/vimrc` you have to fix the `runtimepath`. 
I would try it like this:

```
set runtimepath-=~/vimfiles
set runtimepath^=$USERPROFILE/vimfiles
set runtimepath-=~/vimfiles/after
set runtimepath+=$USERPROFILE/vimfiles/after
```

**After that** you should still change `$HOME`, as others (like netrw) still uses it.

```
let $HOME=$USERPROFILE
```

I'm on Linux, so someone should test this on Windows.

Comment: I did what you said. I put let $HOME = $USERPROFILE and color blue in it. It got blue and echo $HOME echoes home, but vim still starts dog slow until I disconnect the network drive.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>*Running without major issues for a week now so I'm adding this as an alternative answer.*</sub>

I tried all suggestions made here and wherever I could find and the only thing that effectively worked in skipping accessing my networked homefolder was using `gvim --clean`.

- Although the help states that `--clean` is equivalent to `-u DEFAULTS -U NONE -i NONE`, it is not. Using procmon, it was clear that vim was still accessing my network drive.
- It's not a solution. It's good to troubleshoot but I don't want to work with a clean vim.

I ended up **patching the executable** to skip the `HOME*` environment variables all together.
<sub>*It did require me to change my $HOME references in my vimrc.local to an absolute path*</sub>

**Tested on vim 8.1.282.0**
<sub>if the byte sequence is present in your version of vim, I assume it will work as well. You might just as well crash vim but there's little/no harm in trying</sub>

search for following bytes

```
CB 65 00 E8 D1 9B F1 FF 8B E8 83 C4 04 85 ED 74 06 80 7D 00 00 75 7F
68 04 CC 65 00 E8 B8 9B F1 FF 83 C4 04 8B F8
```

and replace with

```
CB 65 00 E8 D1 9B F1 FF 8B E8 83 C4 04 85 ED 74 04 80 7D 00 00 EB 7F
68 04 CC 65 00 E8 B8 9B F1 FF 83 C4 04 8B F8
```

- Original vim's MD5 `E6BBB217EAAB09FE6E2C380D4DF09BD3`
- Patched vim's MD5 `BDAAAC3FA3F6796825A51EF1C0E5B3FD`

**Description of the patch**

Using Ghidra to reverse engineer vim, you can find where references to the `HOME*` environment variables get checked. I have relabeled the autogenerated labels in below screenshots as to show what the block of code does in the context of following/skipping the home folders.

I found two code paths that lead to executing the `Cullprit` code depending on whether or not the `HOME*` environment variables are set. The plan of attack then was to patch the code to *always* flow to `SkipHome`

[image: Original code]

---

**Patch two instructions**

1. Changed the `74 06 JZ` instruction to `74 04 JZ` so instead of jumping 6 bytes into the `Cullprit` code when the `$HOME` environment variable is not set, jump to our unconditional `JMP`
2. Changed the `75 7f JNZ` conditional jump to a `eb 7f JMP` unconditional jump.

[image: Patched code]

---

**Addendum**

That said, vim first checks for a `$HOME` variable and only checks for `$HOMEDRIVE` and `$HOMEPATH` if `$HOME` is empty. Windows, afaik, does not set a `$HOME` variable out of the box so I assume that is simply a cross platform check.

If you don't want to mess with your existing `HOME*` variables and don't want to patch, it looks like you can abuse that fact by setting a `$HOME` variable to whatever you like and skip the `HOME*` code.

for example `setx home <path to your _vimrc>` might just work.

Comment: Fascinating answer; can you explain what the byte patch is/does?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - I have added an explanation of the patch and an addendum.

Comment: Lieven, that is real hacking! I would not recommend that to anyone, but I like it! :-)

Comment: As it turns out, the Addendum does appear in the help as is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58600718/52598)

Answer (score 2):

> Turns out the culprit was
>
> ```
> source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
> ```
>
> in my $HOME/_vimrc. After removing it no files were created anymore.

Never mind. After more testing it didn't work.

**Solution**

Create a vimrc in $VIM with following content

```
let $HOME = $USERPROFILE
```

**This however is not a perfect solution.**

According to the documentation it first searches $HOME and then $VIM. This means there is a slow access to the network drive to check if there exists a vimrc. This is quite noticeable. To fix that you either have to somehow undo the work of the IT guys or open Vim with -u everywhere. Or just keep Vim open forever.

Or you use an editor with manners that saves its configuration in %appdata% like it's supposed to. I'm out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-u` option to give an alternate *.vimrc* file of your choice when starting vim. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4618301/4211238), you can also use the `$MYVIMRC` variable to automate this (this takes precedence over `$HOME`), which should answer your question.

Comment: I know the -u option, but that's a hack. The $MYVIMRC gets set to the first config file it finds so that's not an option either.

Comment: Ok, and what about `HOME=new_address vim ...` ?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: Also what did you mean in your answer, that $MYVIMRC takes precedence? The documentation says "The $MYVIMRC environment variable is
 set to the file that was first found, unless $MYVIMRC was already set
 and when using VIMINIT."

Comment: in bash, if you use `HOME=$USERPROFILE vim` the environment variable `$HOME` will be set to  the content of `$USERPROFILE` only for the following command: `vim`.
Ok, the `$MYVIMRC` only point to a file, it is not used by vim to find the `.vimrc`. Mea culpa.

Comment: I'm on windows.

Comment: @user20406 On Windows, you should be able to use the `set` command to alter the $HOME environment variable before running Vim.

Answer (score 0):

This is @Ralf's answer but with implementation steps tested on Windows 10 with gVim 9.0. By "tested", I just mean gVim now opens and closes immediately with my `_vimrc` settings, so it appears to be ignoring that IT set $HOME to a slow network drive.

1. Create file `$USERPROFILE/_vimrc` with your regular configuration
2. Add this section to the very start of your `_vimrc`:

   ```
    set runtimepath-=~/vimfiles
    set runtimepath^=$USERPROFILE/vimfiles
    set runtimepath-=~/vimfiles/after
    set runtimepath+=$USERPROFILE/vimfiles/after
    let $HOME = $USERPROFILE
    if getcwd() ==? $HOMEDRIVE . $HOMEPATH
      :cd $USERPROFILE
    endif
   ```
3. Create user environment variable `VIMINIT` with the value `source $USERPROFILE/_vimrc`.

   - For a non-admin user account, set these under *Control Panel* → *User Accounts* → *Change my environment variables*
   - If running gVim causes `Error detected while processing VIMINIT: E484: Can't open file C:\Users\<username>/vimrc`, then double-check the environment variable filename exactly matches the actual file. For example, maybe there's an underscore at the start of only one reference.

## Explanation

See @Ralf's answer for most of the explanation. Concerning the `if` statement I added, it is because vim Start Menu shortcuts are installed with the *Start in:* argument set to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`.

- If vim is launched from the Start Menu shortcuts, then `:cd $USERPROFILE` overwrites the working directory.
- If vim is launched by double-clicking a file in Windows Explorer, then don't change the working directory.
- If vim is launched from the command prompt, then don't change the working directory -- unless the command prompt path happens to equal `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`, which hopefully isn't common for you. Otherwise I believe your only option is changing the existing Windows environment variables, which may be against your IT's wishes.
- Check the current working directory by running `:pwd` and/or listing the current directory contents with `:e`  ("e" and a space) then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. I do have `set autochdir` in my `_vimrc`, and it still works as expected.
  [image: Properties of shortcut in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Vim 9.0]

Lastly, arguably `$HOMEDRIVE = $SystemDrive` should also arguably be added to the `_vimrc`. After all, most people would expect $HOME and $HOMEDRIVE to go together. However while the Windows shortcuts clearly use it, I'm not sure anything within vim itself uses it. I removed it from my config after deciding it wasn't worth it.

Comment: Just tested by launching gvim from a command prompt from a different directory, and you are absolutely right it messes with that. I did more investigating and found the Start menu shortcut installed with "Start in" set to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`. I will update my answer.